# Python: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get my code to store messages within txt file using json. Each time a new message comes in, it will add the new message to the array.

The structure will be:

```
{
  "Messages": {
    "Test Contact 2": {
      "0": "\"Message 1"
    },
    "Test Contact 1": {
      "0": "\"Message 1\"",
      "1": "\"Message 2\""
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my current code:

```
class PluginOne(IPlugin):
    def process(self):
        try:
            print("Database")
            data_store('Test contact', 'Text Message')
            pass
        except Exception as exc:
            print("Error in database: " + exc.args)


def data_store(key_id, key_info):
    try:
        with open('Plugins/Database/messages.txt', 'r+') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            data[key_id] = key_info
            f.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, f)
            f.truncate()
        pass
    except Exception as exc:
        print("Error in data store: " + exc.args)
```

when I try to run the code, I get the following error

```
Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 1):

In your exception handler, you're adding `exc.args` to a string. The args attribute [is a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args), which can't be converted to a string implicitly. You could...

```
    # print it seperately
    print("Error in data store")
    print(exc.args)

    # or alternatively
    print("Error in data store: " + str(exc.args))

    # or alternatively
    print("Error in data store: " + str(exc))
```

However, this being a problem in the exception handler, the root cause of the problem is something else, and your current exception handler isn't that great at handling it:

- *without* your exception handler, Python would show a complete traceback of the root cause of the exception, and halt your program.
- *with* your exception handler, only your message is printed *and the program continues*. This might not be what you want.

It would perhaps be better to only `catch` the specific exceptions you know you can recover from.

Comment: You can't concatenate strings and lists. You should find some way to represent the data you want from `exc.args` as a string instead.

Comment: Why would converting it to a list help? A list is also not a string.